# Cannot access part of my json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a php script  returning json data like this:

```
{
    "clients": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "registrationDate": "2011-01-01",
            "rating": "6",
            "registrationNote": "aaa",
            "registrationComment": "bbb",
            "fare": "160"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "registrationDate": "2011-01-01",
            "rating": "4",
            "registrationNote": "xyz",
            "registrationComment": "abc",
            "fare": "160"
        }
    ],
    "stats": {
        "resFounds": 2,
        "resLimit": 4000,
        "execTime": "0.00643",
        "timeStamp": 1465018214
    }
}
```

In a javascript function (let's name it 'showData') I can succesfully pass clients data to another function calling it that way `loadTemplate(my-template, data.clients)`, then next statement in 'showData' function try to access stats object like this `countBox.innerHTML = data.stats.resFound` but instead of 2 it returns 'undefined'.
What's wrong? How am I supposed to access data under 'stats' object ?

Comment: Open up your debugger and put a breakpoint on the `countBox.innerHTML =` line. There, examine `data.stats.resFound`, and you will see its value is `undefined`. Then, examine `data.stats` and you will see it has `resFounds` property, not a `resFound` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `data.stats.resFounds` instead of `data.stats.resFound`

Comment: Yes, I just figure this out and come back there in the hope to delete this before anyone could see it... I really feel ashamed.. 2 hours trying to figure out what's wrong, I was so sure to have checked against typo errors and in the end it was just that! 
Maybe (surely) I need a break! :-)

Comment: lol... it just happens sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming object name to be 'data'

You are passing data.clients and not the full object. Try passing the full object data to the function and then access both of them

```
(my-template, data);
```

And inside function you can then call

```
data.clients
data.stats
```

Also there is a typing error, it should rather be data.stats.resFounds and not data.stats.resFound. There is no key named resFound in your object stats

Comment: You missed the basic problem which is the typo in the property name.

Comment: Agreed but even after correcting that, it will show undefined if full object is not passed to the function